# Start container at a div depending on variable value

Tags: jquery, html, class, time, scroll

I have set up a TV Guide which should start at the current hour. I am using the following Divs to do this right up to 24 for 12am. The timebar scrolls horizontally.

```
<div class="timeListContainer">
    <div class="timeList">
        <div class='timeCell' id="1">
            1am
        </div>
        <div class='timeCell' id="2">
            2am
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script which I am using to do this is only scrolling a bit as it is not seeing the ID. Does anyone have any idea how i can change my code so that at 5pm (17) the time list starts at id 17? I have researched this and tried the .attr('id') in places but i am not able to get it working. The script is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours();


var myDiv = $('.timeCell').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(time) ;
});


$('.timeListContainer').animate({
    scrollLeft: myDiv.offset().left
}, 2000);

});
```

Comment: I can change them to one, two, three or 0100, 0200, 0300 etc but still not sure how it will read this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a combination of `data-*` attributes and attribute selectors

```
<div class="timeCell" data-time="1">
   1am
</div>
<div class="timeCell" data-time="2">
   2am
</div>
```

And then to select the right one:

```
var myDiv = $('.timeCell[data-time="' + time + '"]')
```

(You could do this with your current `id` attributes, but data attributes are a bit more html5-ey)

Another way would be to keep your current structure and filter by the `id`

```
var myDiv = $('.timeCell').filter(function() {
    return this.id == time
});
```